# Why is iodine solution a very effective and with a broad spectrum, bactericide, fungicide and viricide?

Tags: biochemistry

What is the similar property in each that allows a solution of iodine to deactivate and destroy so many species even from different kingdoms?

Comment: What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: None, any guidance where to start ?

Comment: I'd suggest you begin with Google, and use reliable sites like Wikipedia (its usually reliable) or research sites like NCBI, Nature, Wiley, etc.